# Proof verification: A group $G$ of order $p^n$ ($p$ prime) is cyclic iff it is an abelian group having a unique subgroup of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

The theorems are from Rotman's book *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups*.

> **Theorem 2.19** Let $p$ be a prime. A group $G$ of order $p^n$ is cyclic if and only if it is an abelian group having a unique subgroup of order $p$.

Here is my attempt at the proof (of the "if" part):

We have already shown that

> **Theorem 2.17** A group $G$ of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if, for each divisor $d$ of
>   $n$, there is at most one cyclic subgroup of $G$ having order $d$.

By Lagrange's theorem, if $H\leq G$, then $|H|=p^t$ for some $0\leq t\leq n$. It suffices to prove that for each $0\leq t\leq n$, there is at most one cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $p^t$. We use induction on $t$. For $t=0$, the subgroup is trivial. For $t=1$, the uniqueness follows from the hypothesis of the theorem. Suppose $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are two cyclic subgroups of $G$ of order $p^t$, where $2\leq t\leq n$. We see that $\langle a^{p^{t-1}}\rangle$ and $\langle b^{p^{t-1}}\rangle$ are two subgroups of order $p$, thus $\langle a^{p^{t-1}}\rangle=\langle b^{p^{t-1}}\rangle$. In particular, $b^{p^{t-1}}=a^{kp^{t-1}}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $G$ is abelian, we have $1=b^{p^{t-1}}a^{-kp^{t-1}}=(ba^{-k})^{p^{t-1}}$. Set $|ba^{-k}|=p^s$, then $0\leq s\leq t-1$. Observe that $\langle a^{p^{t-s}}\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p^s$, and by induction hypothesis this is the unique subgroup of $G$ of this order, thus $\langle ba^{-k}\rangle=\langle a^{p^{t-s}}\rangle$ and $ba^{-k}=a^{\ell p^{t-s}}$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. From this it follows that $b=a^{k+\ell p^{t-s}}\in\langle a\rangle$, hence $\langle b\rangle\subseteq\langle a\rangle$. The reverse inclusion follows by symmetry, therefore $\langle b\rangle=\langle a\rangle$ and the theorem is proved.

My proof is completely different from the one in the book. Is my proof correct?

Comment: @ccorn Oh sorry, it should be a $t$ instead of $n$...

Comment: Looks OK to me now. There is [another question about the same theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948722) which does not qualify as duplicate here.